# Why are variables declared inside a loop body not considered a redeclaration?

Tags: javascript, scope

Why do `const` or `let` variables declared inside a loop not throw a redeclaration error?

Example:

```js
for (let i = 1; i < 5; ++i){
  const z = "dwan";
}
```

In the second iteration, i.e. when `i === 2`, `z` will be reassigned again in the same scope so this should throw an error but it doesn’t.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: It's not reassigned. `const` only exists in block scope, you get a *new* variable next iteration.

Comment: "Where I am wrong?" - Try to declare `z` outside the loop, and leave only the assignment inside the loop.

Comment: @MisterJojo How did this edit improve the question?

Comment: Because let and const variables are "block scoped" so, as VLAZ stated, in each iteration you get a new z.

Comment: @Andreas there were multiple unnecessary spaces and quotes in its text

Comment: @MisterJojo The question looks exactly the same (with an additional empty line) as before. I would call this an unnecessary edit.

Comment: @Andreas yes it look like the same because moultiples space between words are no visible on final edit

Comment: Corollary of Ozgur Sar’s comment: the same applies to `let`. This isn’t specifically about `const`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it's a **different** `z`, not the same one. You can see that it's a different one if you write a function that closes over it:

```js
for (let i = 1; i<5; i++) {
    const z = 'dwan' + i;
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(z);
    }, i * 200);
}
```

Each loop iteration gets its own *execution context*, which holds any variables/constants declared with modern constructs (`let`, `const`, `class`) within the loop body.

If you declared `z` *outside* the loop's block, so there's just one `z`, you're right, reassignment would fail:

```js
const z = 'dwan0';
for (let i = 1; i<5; i++) {
    z = 'dwan' + i; // <=== Fails here
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(z);
    }, i * 200);
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I go into this in a fair bit of detail in Chapter 2 of my new book; links in my profile if you're interested.